# PHP & MVC: Trouble dynamically creating appropriate MVC Classes

Tags: php, dynamic, autoload, auto-generate

I'm trying to build a CMS using the MVC pattern. The structure of my CMS is as follows:

->**index.php**: entry point. Contains the appropriate includes and creates the frontController which takes a router as it's parameter:

```
$frontController = new FrontController(new Router);
echo $frontController->output();
```

->**router.php**: analyses the URL and defines what the names of each Model,View and Controller will be. By default they are preceded by home, but if the url is of the form `http://localhost/index.php?route=Register` the MVC classes will be named RegisterModel, RegisterView and Register Controller.

```
if(isset ( $_GET ['route'] ))
{
    $this->URL = explode ( "/", $_GET ['route'] );

    $this->route = $_GET ['route'];
    $this->model = ucfirst($this->URL [0] . "Model");
    $this->view = ucfirst($this->URL [0] . "View");
    $this->controller = ucfirst($this->URL [0] . "Controller");
}
else
{
    $this->model = "HomeModel";
    $this->view = "HomeView";
    $this->controller = "HomeController";
    $this->route = "Home";
}
```

->**frontController.php**: This is where I am stuck. When I go to the homepage, it can be visualised correctly because I already have the default HomeModel,HomeView and HomeController classes created. But I created a link that points to register (`localhost/index.php?route=Register`) but the PHP log indicates that the appropriate Register classes weren't created by the frontController class.

```
class FrontController
{
    private $controller;
    private $view;

    public function __construct(Router $router)
    {
        $modelName = $router->model;
        $controllerName = $router->controller;
        $viewName = $router->view;

        $model = new $modelName ();
        $this->controller = new $controllerName ( $model );
        $this->view = new $viewName ( $router->getRoute(), $model );

        if (! empty ( $_GET['action'] ))
            $this->controller->{$_GET['action']} ();
    }
    public function output()
    {
        // This allows for some consistent layout generation code
        return $this->view->output ();
    }
}
```

At this moment I have no idea how to go about solving this issue. And even if I get the classes to be created in the frontController, is there a way to specify that the classes being dynamically generated should extend from a base Model,View,Controller class?
The default HomeView.php looks like this:

```
class HomeView
{
    private $model;
    private $route;
    private $view_file;


    public function __construct($route, HomeModel $model)
    {
        $this->view_file = "View/" . $route . "/template.php";
        echo $this->view_file;
        $this->route = $route;
        $this->model = $model;
    }

    public function output()
    {
        require($this->view_file);
    }
}
```

Any indications on anything that might help me get unstuck or a pointer in the right direction would be much appreciated.

EDIT1:
I forgot to add a summary of my two issues:
1. I would like to understand why the classes aren't being created in the FrontController class...
2. Once created how would I access those classes? Answer is in the comment section. Using the PHP spl_autoload_register function.

Thanks All!

Comment: Are you doing it all by yourself? Why not use an existing framework instead?

Comment: What a verbose way to ask about `spl_autoload_register` and `is_a` functions. Seriously though, why don't you grab one of a zillion already existing PHP MVC frameworks if not to use it then at least to see how things can be architected before you attempt to write your own.

Comment: @lafor: "architected"? What a verbose way to say "design" `;-)`.

Comment: I underlined two issues that I'm having. Sorry for not providing a summary at the end. I have provided one now. Thanks for helping with my second issue

Comment: I finally understood what I'm supposed to do. Thanks for the help all